# Optimizing Reading from excel file into record in clojure

Tags: clojure

What would be the best way to read from an excel file a specific number of rows and updating them in a record with each row being a new instance of the record

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to save excel file as csv file and then apply usual [tools](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv)

```
(defrecord Record [W1 W2 W3])

(defn read-csv [fname count]
  (with-open [file (reader fname)]
    (doall (take count (map (comp first csv/read-csv)
                            (line-seq file))))))

(map #(apply ->Record %) (read-csv "1.csv" 3))
->(#Record{:W1 "1", :W2 "one", :W3 "A"}
   #Record{:W1 "2", :W2 "two", :W3 "B"}
   #Record{:W1 "3", :W2 "three", :W3 "C"})
```

Comment: Would it be good if you could explain suppose i would like to access W2 of the 1st row in the map how do i go about doing it? Pardon my question as i am still very new to clojure 

->(#Record{:W1 "1", :W2 "one", :W3 "A"}
   #Record{:W1 "2", :W2 "two", :W3 "B"}
   #Record{:W1 "3", :W2 "three", :W3 "C"})

In this case, the records seems to be updated manually instead of reading from the file. Could you explain it clearer

Comment: You can access to the field `:W3` of first record by `(:W3 (first records))`. I've used `->` to show output of the expression `(map #(apply ->Record %) (read-csv "1.csv" 3))` that does all the work.

Comment: It seems my IDE has this compiler exception 
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: reader in this context, compiling:(ShipDataRecord.clj:90) 
When i evaluated the function read-csv

Comment: Add https://github.com/clojure/data.csv to your project and `require` that as `csv`.

Comment: I evalulated the whole file but it does not seem to have an issue. However, when i evalulate each line it seems to have a problem even when i evalulated the require line first.

here is my code 

`(ns ShipDataRecord
  (:import [java.util.Date]
   [org.joda.time.DateTime]
   [org.joda.time.Seconds]
   [org.joda.time.format.*]
   [semsav.RecordSplitter]))
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use Martin Jul's [docjure](https://github.com/ative/docjure).